# AUCTeX column marker

Tags: emacs, elisp, auctex

I am using Emacs and just built AUCTeX for LaTeX. Anyway, as I was using column-marker extension while writing in LaTeX without AUCTeX, it is not working anymore with it. I was looking over the internet but couldn't find any help. Is there an elisp code line that allows to use column-marker on AUCTeX?

Comment: It's been about a year since you asked, and there has been no answer. I suggest you send your question to the AUCTex mailing list: `auctex@gnu.org`.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me in emacs 24.3.1 with the built-in auctex and column-marker.el Update #: 312.

Here you have got an example (right window):
[image]

The deviation from the straight line comes from the different fonts/font sizes used for the caret and exponent, for the section titles and so on.
Inspite of that column-marker shows one the column with the specific character distance from the beginning of line.